# TableView content changes after device rotating

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an application with a table view that contains 3 sections. Every thing is okay with displaying data, but when i change the device orientation (from portrait to Landscape and vis versa )  an additional number of rows is added to my table View

Indeed, when debugging my Application, i figured out that `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is executed every time i rotate the device.

Can some Good person tell me how can i fix that problem ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you implementing any of the view controller rotation related methods? Do you implement 'viewWillLayoutSubview? Do any of these call any table related methods such as inserting rows or sections? Do any of these methods add data to whatever data structures are used by your table view's data source?

Comment: No, No one of these methods, i've implemented only the essential methods to display data in a specific section.

Comment: Try this - run the app in the debugger. Get the app up and running in one orientation. Now set a breakpoint in the numberOfSections method and the numberOfRowsInSection method. Now rotate the device. Check the results of these methods. Most likely the latter is returning more rows than expected. Now you need to figure out why. Show your code for numberOfRowsInSection.

Comment: i've added numberOfRowsInSection's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected, your issue is that you are adding items to your data source data in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method. Every time the table asks how many rows are in a section, you add more data to the data structures. Remember, the data source methods will be called many different times.

You need to create your data structures once, outside of any of the data source methods. Your data source methods should be read-only with regard to your data structures. They should simple return a count. No other processing should be done in the data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code !!!

```
`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section==0) {
    for (int i=0; i < self.TiersArray.count; i++) {
         if (([[[self.TiersArray objectAtIndex:i]t_client] isEqualToNumber:one])||        ([[[self.TiersArray objectAtIndex:i]t_client] isEqualToNumber:three])) 
   {
            [ClientsArray addObject:[self.TiersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

    }
return self.ClientsArray.count;
}
else if(section==1){
    for (int i=0; i < self.TiersArray.count; i++) {
        if (([[[self.TiersArray objectAtIndex:i]t_client]isEqualToNumber:two])||([[[self.TiersArray objectAtIndex:i]t_client]isEqualToNumber:three])) {
            [ProspectsArray addObject:[self.TiersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

    }
    return self.ProspectsArray.count;
}
else{
    for (int i=0; i < self.TiersArray.count; i++) {
        if ([[[self.TiersArray objectAtIndex:i]t_fournisseur] isEqualToNumber:one ]) {
            [FournisseurArray addObject:[self.TiersArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }

    }
    return self.FournisseurArray.count;
}
}
```

`